# How to group Arrays with similar values

Tags: ruby, arrays, sorting, grouping

I'm looking for a smart way to group any number of arrays with similar values (not necessarily in the same order). The language I'm using is ruby but I guess the problem is pretty language agnostic.

Given

```
a = ['foo', 'bar']
b = ['bar', 'foo']
c = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
d = ['what', 'ever', 'else']
e = ['foo', 'baz', 'bar']
```

I'd like to have a function that tells me that

- a & b are in one group
- c & e are in one group
- d is it's own group

I can think of a number of not so smart ways of doing this very inefficient, like I could compare each array's values to each others array's values.
Or I could check if ((a - b) + (b - a)).length == 0 for all combinations of arrays and group the ones that result in 0. Or I could check if a.sort == b.sort for all combinations of arrays.

I'm sure someone before me has solved this problem way more efficiently. I just can't seem to find how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with `sort` without doing it "for all combinations of arrays" but doing it only for all arrays (Schwartzian transform).

```
arrays = [a, b, c, d, e]
arrays.group_by{|array| array.sort}.values
```